# Is it possible to host a asp.net web-application in folder and drive different from C:\Inetpub\wwwroot?

Tags: asp.net, networking, web-applications, web-hosting

I have a problem.

I have less than 5GB available,
now I have to host a web application on it, I need at least 20GB space for it,
it is not possible to increase the space on C drive without formatting it.

So is it possible to host the web app from any other drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you hosting your application with?

If it's with your own IIS then yes, you can just change the directory of the website.

In IIS right click the site, go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings.

Change the Physical location to your site on a different drive.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly .....  Yes the files for your web application can be on a different drive (and often are) you just need to configure IIS to look at the correct path and set the correct security on the folder